# How to get single row from SQLite database in Windows Store apps?

Tags: sql, sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

If I want single primitive value like `int`, `string`, `float` etc I can do like this.

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
{
    double i = db.CreateCommand("select salary from PersonMaster where personId = ?", 9).ExecuteScalar<double>();
}
```

If I try to return whole object of person master i.e. single row the below code returns null

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
{
    PersonMaster objPersonMaster = db.CreateCommand("select * from PersonMaster where personId = ?", 9).ExecuteScalar<PersonMaster>();
}
```

I compulsory have to use this

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
{
    List<PersonMaster> lstPersonMaster = db.Query<PersonMaster>("select * from PersonMaster where personId = ?", 9);
    PersonMaster objPersonMaster = lstPersonMaster.First();
}
```

Is there any way to get single row as object, rather than dealing with `List<T>`

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using [SQLite-Net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). If that is the case you can use the `Find` method. `Find` gets an object using its primary key.

The `personId` field needs the `PrimaryKey` attribute as follows:

```
public class PersonMaster
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int personId { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public decimal salary { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use `Find` like so:

```
// get person 9
PersonMaster person9 = db.Find<PersonMaster>(9);
```

Comment: What to do if I have no primary key in the table ? If my whe, then how can I do that ?

Comment: @Xyroid - If you don't have a key, then you have to use `First`

Comment: @Xyroid: `Find()` can also take a predicate: `db.Find<PersonMaster>(person => person.name == "Xyroid")`

Answer (score 1):

You can either use "TOP(1) yourquery" or "yourquery LIMIT 1"

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get rid of the list step, you can do it directly:

```
PersonMaster objPersonMaster = db.Query<PersonMaster>("select * from PersonMaster where personId = ?", 9).First();
```

Of course you have to deal with a possible exception in case nothing is returned, but you should do this also with the list approach anyway.

Comment: That I know, but I don't want to go in `List<T>` way.